# Href variable en php no funciona

Tags: php

Tengo un problema que no entiendo y creo que está bien programado.

Os pongo el código que tengo.

```
            $imgfiletype = pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $imageextension = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");
            if (in_array($imgfiletype, $imageextension)){
                echo '<a href="'.$file_path.'"/><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="'.$file_path.'"></a>';
            }
```

Lo que me ocurre es que el atributo src funciona perfectamente y me muestra las imágenes pero el href una vez actualizado el archivo en mi web no funciona y se muestra así (adjunto foto)

[image]

No entiendo porque no se forma el enlace y aparece por partes mientras que en el atributo src aparece bien.
¿alguien sabe porque pasa esto?
Gracias

EDIT 1.

Si dejo el código sin la imagen tampoco funciona el atributo href:

```
if (in_array($imgfiletype, $imageextension)){
                echo '<a href="'.$file_path.'"/>link</a>';
            }
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código donde creas la variable `$file_path`. No hay razón para que sí te funcione en la imagen y no en el enlace. Probablemente tienes alguna función que elimina las diagonales al crear el enlace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gracias por responder. Al final no sé qué ocurría pero se solucionó de la siguiente manera por si a alguien le interesa. Añadí el atributo target="_blank" y funciona correctamente.

```
if (in_array($imgfiletype, $imageextension)){
   echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$file_path.'" ><img class="card-img-top img-fluid" 
   src="'.$file_path.'"></a>';
            }
```

Comment: Qué bien que pudiste solucionarlo, pero el atributo `target` no tiene que ver con que el `href` no se mostrara correctamente.

Comment: Para mi el error estaba en: `"/>`

Answer (score 1):

debes tener un error con la variable `$file_path` 
verifica que contenga el dato correcto

el `href` soporta las url `absolute` y `relative` pero como lo tienes en el `src` de la imagen creo que no lo acepta.

creo que por ahí esta el problema.

Comment: Sería muy genial si le explicaras el proceso para que tu aporte tenga mayor contexto, checa [answer]

Comment: Gracias por responder. La variable $file_path funciona perfectamente. Los tiros deben ir por lo segundo que dices. Gracias por el indicio voy a investigarlo.